# Selenium times out when trying to click <a> tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to use selenium to click a button it works fine on every page except on 1 single page and on 1 single element in that page. I have extracted it an made a reproducible example. I have tried everything I can think of but the item never gets clicked. I have observed the console with no luck, if i click it manually it works.

Here is my index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a id="go" href="javascript:void(0);" class="button_next font_two" onclick="nextStep()">Confirm
    </a>

    <script>
      function nextStep() {
        console.log("moving...")
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is what i have tried to automate it

```
    nextBtn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "go"))
    )

    nextBtn.click()
```

From above the error I get is timeout

I also tried to do this

```
...
nextBtn.send_keys(u'\ue007')
...
```

but also a timeout

then i tried to do it a bit differently

```
nextBtn = driver.find_element_by_id("go")
...
```

This time I get `element not interactable error`

I tried using `XPATH` instead but no luck, I have also tried adding `driver.implicitly_wait(20)` as well as getting a different element from page before doing this and also no luck. at this point I ran out of ideas.

Comment: I have tried that as well and sadly still didn't work. I also tried firefox and chrome drivers both same result.

Comment: I am working of localhost. I just used `xampp` and ran the above `index.html`. Also it should work because i have literally done this 100s of times. I just dont understand. Though, I  was able to reproduce as noted in the question.

Comment: Yup i tried it, nothing at all.

Comment: I was able to fix it finally.. it took me 2 days. `javaScript = "document.getElementById('go').click();"
    driver.execute_script(javaScript)` this did it.

Comment: yea it didn't work at first try but I closed everything, stopped the web server and ran that again and it worked. Literally as we are talking I tried that. Thank you so much for the help though. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to this, `.execute` is to execute a driver command where as `.execute_script` is to execute JavaScript code.

So, doing this should work for you :

```
javaScript = "document.getElementById('go').click();"
driver.execute_script(javaScript)

# OR Directly calling that function which will be called after click

javaScript ="nextStep()"
driver.execute_script(javaScript)
```

You can learn more about it from [`execute`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute) and [`execute_script`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute)
.